# tcpdump filter src dst port

Tags: filter, tcpdump

I need to sniff voip traffic on 5060 port.
And at the same time I need to exclude all packets where src port 5060 and dst port 5061

I need something like:

```
tcpdump -i any -vvv -s0 port 5060 and (not src port 5060 and not dst port 5061)
```

but the second part of the filter should be related to a single packet, not all traffic. How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to see all traffic to or from port 5060, *except* for traffic that's from port 5060 and to port 5061?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
port 5060 and not (src port 5060 and dst port 5061)
```