# tcpdump: Using AND and OR in a compound filter

Tags: filter, tcpdump

I'm trying to add a filter to a `tcpdump` stream.

The expression I'm trying to run is:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -U -w - host 192.168.2.29 and (port 22222 or port 22221 or port 80)
```

This particular format throws:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

I expected this to work based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782333/tcpdump-filter-src-dst-port).

The following work without throwing an error:

```
a)  tcpdump -i eth0 -U -w - host 192.168.2.29
b)  tcpdump -i eth0 -U -w - port 22222
```

I've tried every permutation of association all throwing the same error.

Comment: It’s the shell that’s unhappy. Add a \ before the parens.

Comment: nope - It still throws the error.  I tried both just inserting and breaking into two lines using \.  I've also tried enclosing the whole thing trying to pass as a single argument.  No joy.

Comment: The error message itself is telling you it’s a bash issue. 

Alternately put the whole expression (starting with ‘host’) in quotes.

Comment: The quotes did it - - keeping as it with the quotes allows the whole express to pass as a single argument.  Thanks.

Comment: Using quotes is probably easiest and most general, but it's for sure the shell was doing this to you before. I tested the same `tcpdump` command, and it worked with proper quoting: `tcpdump -i em1 -U -w - host 192.168.2.29 and \(port 22222 or port 22221 or port 80\)`.  Something's different about your environment...

Comment: Oh - I see now.  The \ is used as an 'escape' for the next character.  I blew it a couple of ways - (a) used a space after the \ which would be a problem and (b) only used it on the first "(" while the second ")" would have thrown an error.  I've also found the references to using the \ as a quote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Summarizing the comments for an answer:

The easiest way to deal with the tcpdump expression is to put it all in quotes, because otherwise the shell gets in the way anytime there are special characters. Parentheses are the most common troublesome metacharacters, but many others get to play as well: `[` `]` `&` and others, and anytime you refine your expression you have to check that you didn't add something dangerous.

So quotes are the easy way:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -U -w - 'host 192.168.2.29 and (port 22222 or port 22221 or port 80)'
```

But escaping the metacharacters works too and is directly responsive to the OP's question:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -U -w - host 192.168.2.29 and \(port 22222 or port 22221 or port 80\)
```

Personally, I prefer the quotes.

Comment: Notably, `[` and `]` on their own as tokens/arguments (with unquoted whitespace on either side) are not special to the shell (that's why the `[` used for conditionals has to have a space on each side, unlike the built-in `[[` added by later shells like `bash` - because syntactically `[` *by itself* is not special, it's just a command name, which is another name for the command `test`) - so if `tcpdump` supports `[` for grouping too, you could have close to the not-having-to-quote ergonomics.

Comment: Also! In `zsh`, you can double up unquoted parentheses in an argument like so `((` and then it still works: `tcpdump -i eth0 -U -w - host 192.168.2.29 and ((port 22222 or port 22221 or port 80))`... I find this nicer to type than backslash or quotes, since it doesn't require me to move my fingers to as many different special characters. Sadly that only works on `zsh`.